# Running 10000 workers for specific tasks vs running handful workers

Tags: web-worker, worker, horizontal-scaling

I have a system in which I have 1000 products which are created asynchronously by pushing them in a queue on one end and workers listening to queue on other end. Products are created by calling microservices of third patry providers.

Below are the two approaches for implementation:

**First approach**
In this approach we will push every product in their own specific queue, i.e. Product A will go to Queue A and Product B will go to Queue B.
If I am running 10 workers to listen on each queue, so total of 10,000 workers are running on my system.

This approach make sure that all my products run in isolation, i.e. third party api performance of one product does not affect other product (as they run in different queue by different worker), but many idle workers sitting here will increase load on server (as all products are not getting created on large scale).

**Second approach**
In this approach I have tried to reduce number of workers by using single queue and running n workers (n <= 1.5 * number_of_cores) listening to same queue. 
We have reduced number of workers here which will definitely bring load on each server down due to idle workers, but here if any providers api started responding slowly, whole system will get impacted.

Please suggest on which approach I should go with, or any other approach which can fit this usecase.
Thanks